# What is the best practice regarding Source code managment?

Tags: svn, version-control

We are geographically  diverse team of software developers working on an ERP system.
We are using SVN as a version control system. 
We have 4 environments before the code moves to production system.

I want to know what are the best practice, regarding BRANCHING, MERGING when using SVN in such situation.

Currently we face a problem that one file has 4 changes. The customer wants only 2 changes to be in X (yearly 4 main releases and 4 minor releases) release.

The problem we face  are: 
Too many Branches.
complicated Manual merge.
losing track or changes
overwriting someone else s code .

Can anyone answere how can one solve this issues by using SVN as a better tool, which it is.

Thanks and Regards, Kedar Hukeri.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a process how to get code to main branch would help more than different tool (other than source control system with good diff/merge).

It depends on your process but generally:

- good practice for bigger teams is to
  have a separate branch per new
  feature/fix
- developer before releasing code to
  main line would pull the latest from
  main to his branch and run all the
  tests to make sure it all works
- if the team is big you may have to
  consider a release manager - a person
  to manage the releases and simply
  freezing the main branch and managing
  the order in which the features go in
- even better, have release branches
  and a person that is allowed to merge
  new features into it, developers
  submit note that new feature is ready
  and one person merges the changes
  into main branch
- freeze release branch before release and run
  tests to iron bugs, don't allow new
  features in only bug fixes when you
  are near release date
- depends on number of commits but you
  can create smaller releases which are
  more tested to establish milestones
  and functionality to be know to work
  in each point release

In the end, no matter what the exact process is the main point is that the developers understand the procedures and someone enforces it.

Answer (score 2):

One of the first places to start is one you may have already consulted: [Version Control With Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  Also check out the [list of books](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#books) cited by the [Subversion Dev Team](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read this: http://oreilly.com/catalog/practicalperforce/chapter/ch07.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I share your pain, had the same problems with SVN, as soon as you start branching a lot( and you have to in order to deal with all the different cases in the life of a project ), there's a big pain when you start merging, if the branch lasts long enough, the merge is a whole "project" by itself ...

For sure better practices are useful, but it would be nice if the tool would allow to easily enforce some of them.

I've been recommended Mercurial and I'm looking into it currently to replace SVN, it's distributed by design, has ( I'm told ) a better merge tool and a better/easier branch/repositories management, so you might want to look into it as well.

Comment: If you're using SVN, then SVK is an awesome adjunct tool to use to manage merge complexity in Subversion.  As a tool, subversion doesn't offer a lot of the security/flexibility of release management that something like ClearCase does.  I'm not sure they'll try to fix that gap - their stated goal was a better CVS than CVS, and that they've managed amazingly well.

Comment: Changing source control can be a hassle. Have you considered looking at better Diff tools, like darthcoder suggests? I have a third party SVN client, but I like the third party diff tool I have so much that I use it rather than using the tool included with my operating system (Apple FileMerge). Araxis FileMerge is a great tool, and I like Changes the best (OS X only, unfortunately).

Comment: @darthcoder & Andrew : Apparently Mercurial can easily import a SVN repository, retrieving also the commits history, so it might not be very complex, but I'll look into the tools you guys are suggesting, thanks a lot for those pointers !

Comment: svn merge tracking goes a long ways toward simplifying things.  Make sure you use 1.6 and know the ramifications of how it works.

Comment: Indeed Jeremy, I'm not using the 1.6 version, I'll look into that also, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is Unified Change Management, and that's something that Subversion isn't really designed to do well (IMO).  It's going to take some amount of manual effort to manage changes.  But assuming you have decent issue-tracking systems in place, here's what many places I've worked have done:

```
main branch (trunk)  - new feature development here 
  |- release-1.0  - locked release branch 
  |--- release-sp1
  |--- release-patches - patch release fix stream (new fixes merged here)
  |------ release-sp1-issue# - this is where you make your bug fixes 
                               before merging them. 
                               This issue# is the bug-id in your tracking system.
```

Once a bug is fixed and committed to the patch release, you delete the old -issue# branch.  That keeps branches from getting out of control but lets you keep changesets small.

Maintainers can be enforced by making release trunks writable only to integrators.  Using subversion via apache: [Subversion/Apache Permissions](http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2007/10/29/customizing-subversion-permissions/), you could create a group, integrators, and set the following permissions on your project

```
project 
  |- branches  (everyone: rw) 
      |- individual-fixes
  |- release-branches: (integrator: rw, everyone: ro) 
      |- release-1.0-fixes
      |- release-2.0-fixes
  |- trunk     (integrator: rw, everyone: ro) <- new dev goes here!!!!
  |- tags      (integrator: rw, everyone: ro) 
      |- release-1.0
      |- release-1.0-sp1 
      |- release-2.0
```

Then each merge is small, well tracked, and only a small group of people can do merging.  This creates a bottleneck on your merge team, however.  I've never worked with a large git/mercurial team to see how this works.

You would implement something similar for feature fixes as well, but off your trunk instead.

Comment: Do you keep your release branches in the development trunk? I'm having difficulty understanding this. I use the standard Subversion structure, so I keep releases in the tags folder. Sounds like this would become cluttered quickly.

Comment: tags are read-only.  You don't integrate/merge into these.  But having a separate release-branches tree, you can control access to integrators.  Ideally once something is tagged, it's release-branch is removed.  Once SP1 ships, that's it, no more changes.  In this instance, assuming 1 release, you only have two branches, one, the trunk (new development), and the release-fixes stream, which will eventually become a new service pack.